# Python 2.7 mmap http post runtime issue: TypeError: read() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python-2.7, post, mmap

Using python 2.7 with mmap to perform http upload, encountered runtime exception with:

```
fdata = fp.read()
    TypeError: read() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Here's the code :

```
    import requests
    dcs_session = requests.Session()
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        with contextlib.closing(mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, 
access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)) as mmap_obj:
            resp = dcs_session.post(url, headers=additional_headers, 
data=form_data,files={'file': mmap_obj}, timeout=1000, verify=verify_arg)
```

Here's the Exception :

```
    fdata = fp.read()
    TypeError: read() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
    
    ERROR (/usr/bin/dca.py:563 : dcs_push  Stack trace - Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/dca.py", line 540, in dcs_push
        verify=verify_arg)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in post
        return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 494, in request
        prep = self.prepare_request(req)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 437, in prepare_request
        hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 308, in prepare
        self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 496, in prepare_body
        (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 159, in _encode_files
        fdata = fp.read()
    TypeError: read() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Answer (score 2):

`mmap`'s `read` method required you to pass an argument prior to Python 3.3. It's not a drop-in replacement for a file object, and even if it was, it wouldn't do any good to use it, because the `read` method is making a copy anyway, so you're not avoiding any allocated memory usage. Just pass the file object instead of `mmap`ing it, or upgrade to modern Python (Python 2 has been out of support for well over a year; stop writing new code in it).